# Navbar not loading component

Tags: reactjs

When I click on "Report1 dropdown under Report tab"  code does not load  the component Report1Component.
Only the url changes to `localhost:3000/report1`. How to make my component load?

When I hit this url: `localhost:3000/report1` directly in browser then only `Report1Component` loads.

My Nav bar code looks like below

```
<navbar
<item href="/home" name="Home Tab" />
<item  id="report"  name="Report Tab" >
<item id="report1" href="/Report1" name="Report1 dropdown under Report tab" >
<item href="/Report2" id="report2" name="Report2 dropdown under Report tab" >
</item>
</navbar>
```

And my app.js looks below  (snippet)

```
<Route path="/Report1" exact component={Report1Component} />
            <Route component={InvalidUrl} />
```

Comment: Is it a copy paste mistake or is <navbar missing its closing > ?

Comment: typing mistake. i corrected .is my idea correct.or do i need to to include onclick something?

Comment: does your console show any errors? could you post the entire react-router code?